# Error in console: angular2 and webpack server

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

I have this error in my console. Please I need help. When I run my app I have this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Parameter "key" requiredErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54ngZone.onError.subscribe.next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:93SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294webpackJsonp.630.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:369webpackJsonp.630.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:168ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:460
error_handler.js:59 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:59ngZone.onError.subscribe.next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:93SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294webpackJsonp.630.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:369webpackJsonp.630.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:168ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:460
error_handler.js:60 Error: Parameter "key" required
    at new Error (native)
    at TranslateService.instant (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:59039:19) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber._error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/main.bundle.js:3730:88) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:18084:16) [angular]
    at SafeSubscriber.error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:18045:26) [angular]
    at Subscriber._error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:17978:26) [angular]
    at Subscriber.error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:17952:18) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:17978:26) [angular]
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:17952:18) [angular]
    at XMLHttpRequest.onError (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:102898:34) [angular]
    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/vendor.bundle.js:53756:37) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.630.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:8486:36) [angular]
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.630.Zone.runTask (https://dev.snug.menu:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:8254:47) [<root> => angular]ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:60ngZone.onError.subscribe.next @ application_ref.js:348schedulerFn @ async.js:93SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:234SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:183Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ async.js:79NgZone.triggerError @ ng_zone.js:333inner.inner.fork.onHandleError @ ng_zone.js:294webpackJsonp.630.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:369webpackJsonp.630.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:168ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:460
Subscriber.js:238 Uncaught Error: Parameter "key" required
```

Comment: Hmm this is hard to debug from this stack trace. Is this a plain angular-cli app? What version of the cli are you using? Are you running 'ng serve' ? Any other info would be helpful.

Comment: version 3.0.0 angular-cli and i run with 'npm run serve'

Comment: there is no 3.0.0 version for angular cli, the latest is 1.0.0 (as of today). and `npm run serve` runs the script 'serve' from your package.json, please post you'r package json, and any code that uses TranslateService. Again, hard to debug just from this stack trace.

Comment: this package.json

Comment: version 1.0.0-beta.19-3